# Corrupted file display after uploading to Firebase Storage using JavaScript and React

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm currently working on a React application where users can upload images to Firebase Storage. The file upload process seems to be working fine, but when I try to display the uploaded image, it appears to be corrupted. I'm seeking assistance in understanding what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it.

Here's an overview of my code and the steps I'm taking:

I have a form where users can select an image file using an  element.
When the form is submitted, I handle the file upload in the handleSubmit function.
Here's an excerpt of the relevant code:

```
//metadata declaration during initialisation
 const metadata = {
    contentType: 'image/png',
  };

// Inside the handleSubmit function
const file = fileInputRef.current; // Retrieves the file from the file input element
const fileName = "MYFILENAME"; // Constructs a unique file name in code
const storageRef = ref(storage, `${fileName}.png`); 
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata);

uploadTask.on(
  (error) => {
    // Handle error
  },
  (snapshot) => {
    // Progress event listener: called periodically to track the upload progress
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref) // Retrieves the download URL of the uploaded file
        .then((downloadURL) => {
          console.log("File available at", downloadURL); // the download URL routes to a corrupt document 
          updateDoc(docRef, { displayURL: downloadURL }) // Updates the user document in Firestore with the download URL
            .then(() => {
              console.log("File uploaded successfully"); // success message to the console is always received 
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                  // Handle error
            });
  }
);
```

The file does get uploaded to Firebase Storage successfully, but when I try to display it by setting the src attribute of an  tag to the download URL, the image appears corrupted or broken. I've also noticed that when I try to view the image directly from Firebase Storage, I encounter the same issue.

I've ensured that the file being uploaded is a valid PNG image and that the content type is set correctly in the metadata object. I'm not sure what could be causing the corruption during the upload process or when retrieving the file for display.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on what could be causing this problem? I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue.

See images result below:

[image: Corrupted image]

Comment: Are you passing the correct parameters to `UploadTask.on()`?  It looks like the first argument should be a `TaskEvent` - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.uploadtask.md#uploadtaskon